# Find depth to last ul in list

Tags: jquery, html-lists, depth

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/robincox/9nNej/34/, the question is in the javaScript part. Or you can see it in this code:

```
$(".off-canvas-list li:not(:has(ul))").addClass("liLast");
$(".off-canvas-list li").has("ul").addClass("liHasChild");
$("li.liHasChild > a").click(
    function () {

        if ($(this).siblings("ul").hasClass("opened")) {

            // Here I want to find the sibling ul tag to the a tag I clicked.
            // Then I want to check that ul tags children after an li with the class "liHasChild".
            // If such a tag isn't found the value of 1 shall be stored in a variable named depth.
            // If such a tag is found (an li with the class "liHasChild") then search it's child
            // ul tag after an li with the class "liHasChild"
            // If such a tag isn't found the value of 2 shall be stored in a variable named depth.

        } else {

            // Open clicked a tags sibling ul

            $(this).siblings("ul").slideDown();
            $(this).siblings("ul").addClass("opened");

        }

    }
);

$(".off-canvas-list ul").css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following recursive function:

```
function depthOf(elem){
    var $children = $(elem).siblings("ul").children("li.liHasChild"); 
    if($children.length){ //If there are children with children
        return 1 + depthOf($children.find("a")); //count and go deeper
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
if ($(this).siblings("ul").hasClass("opened")) {
    alert(depthOf(this));
}
```